# Select rows having 3 fields/columns with the same value on the same row

Tags: sql

I'm trying to query a table with multiple columns that could possibly contain the same value (in this case, dates) in 3 fields/column.

Example:

```
 Account   Address    Start_date    End_date    Billing_Start_Date  Billing_End_Date    Last_Billed_Date
 ABC       123 Main    1/1/2016     NULL         1/1/2016             NULL                 12/23/2016
 DEF       789 Main    3/1/2016      2/1/2017    3/1/2016             2/1/2017             2/1/2017
```

I would like the query to provide any other accounts that is similar to account DEF in the above example.  Where the values in the End_Date, Billing_End_Date, and Last_Billed_Date fields are the same or matching.

Comment: Explain the logic. Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple check in the SQL `WHERE` clause if I've understood your question correctly.

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  End_Date = Billing_End_Date
  AND End_Date = Last_Billed_Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would return all rows with dates the same as 'DEF' account:

```
SELECT * FROM Account
WHERE End_date = '2/1/2017' AND 
Billing_Start_Date = '3/1/2016' AND 
Billing_End_Date = '2/1/2017'
```